# What's the most efficient way to query MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with over 4 million documents. I tried receiving documents the following way.

```
db.getCollection(collectionName).find(new Document("lang", lang))
        .skip(skip).limit(limit).sort(new Document("date", 1));
```

took 443 seconds.

```
db.getCollection(collectionName).find(new Document("lang", lang))
         .sort(new Document("date", 1)).skip(skip).limit(limit);
```

took 529 seconds.

Both queries delivered exactly the same results.

Was this due to varying network speed? What is the call stack here? I expected the results to be different according to the order of the method calls.

Comment: You can `explain` the queries to get more information. Also make sure you use the right (and non-redundant) indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to `explain`. What do you mean by use the right indexes?

Comment: I mean to index your collections with the right document fields, aside from the default index on `_id`. Indexing will depend on the queries you use of course.

Comment: @Pete an example of a redundant index would be index_1 (a,b) and index_2(a,b,c), because index_1 is a superset of index_2.

Answer (score 0):

Both query returns the same result. The first one would limit the result improving network IO and then do a sort, while the second would sort on all and then limit the result.

Use indexing to improve query performance. If a query searches multiple fields, create a compound index. Scanning an index is much faster than scanning a collection.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 queries are equivalent. See below example and quote from the [db.collection.find() documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#combine-cursor-methods) on Combine Cursor Methods.

```
db.bios.find().sort( { name: 1 } ).limit( 5 )
db.bios.find().limit( 5 ).sort( { name: 1 } )
```

> The two statements are equivalent; i.e. the order in which you chain
>   the limit() and the sort() methods is not significant. Both statements
>   return the first five documents, as determined by the ascending sort
>   order on ‘name’.

As @Mena suggested the [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) command is useful for understanding what a query is doing and the docs also have info on [indexing strategies](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/).